# Integrate PHP plugin from Joomla in an Android Application

Tags: php, android, plugins, joomla

I have a website running with **Joomla!**, and I'm using **PhocaGallery**, which is a component used for managing a photo gallery.
In my articles, I simply put a **tag**, for example :

```
{phocagallery view=category|categoryid=2|limitcount=2}
```

This tag displays simply 2 images from the category which has 2 as ID.

I'm developing my own application for this website, and when I load an article on it, I have simply the **tag displayed**, **without images**, that's normal.

I have the long PHP code for this plugin.

I would like to know how :

**1. Detect the tag when the article is loadind in application
 2. Call PHP script in the application to browse good images
 3. Display images**

The problem I think, is that the PHP code may call to folders on the website, and I think the application can't...

Do you think it's possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. detect the tag: use a regular expression to parse the parameters you need
2. inkoking the plugin is pretty straightforward, just make sure you're making all the necessary resources available i.e. most likely you will want to load the whole joomla framework.  Since you're just querying a single table you might be better off doing it on your own with mysql, it will save you a lot of time both developing and at runtime
3. just output the

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions, but I didn't succeed in doing anything... Can you give more precise instructions ? :)